# Where clause in Mutiple table sql joins

Tags: sql

TABLES

```
CREATE TABLE LocalBusiness
(
    BusinessID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    BusinessName VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
    TypeID INT,
    Latitude DECIMAL (10,2),
    Longitude DECIMAL (10,2),
    Web_address VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,
    Postcode VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,
    official_rating int,
    min_price NUMBER(4,2),
    max_price NUMBER(4,2),

    FOREIGN KEY (TypeID) REFERENCES LocalBusinessType (TypeID),
    CONSTRAINT chk_Officialrating CHECK (official_rating> 0 AND  official_rating<6 )
);

CREATE TABLE Address
(
    AddressID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    BusinessID INT,
    AreaID INT,
    Address VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,
    Postcode VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (BusinessID) REFERENCES LocalBusiness (BusinessID),
    FOREIGN KEY (AreaID) REFERENCES Area (AreaID)
);

CREATE TABLE Phone
(
    PhoneNoID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    PhoneNo VARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL, 
    BusinessID INT,
    Description VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (BusinessID) REFERENCES LocalBusiness (BusinessID),
    CONSTRAINT PhoneNo_unique UNIQUE (PhoneNo) 
);

CREATE TABLE Email
(
    EmailID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    email_address VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,
    BusinessID INT,
    Description VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (BusinessID) REFERENCES LocalBusiness (BusinessID),
    CONSTRAINT email_unique UNIQUE (email_address)
);

CREATE TABLE Area
(
    AreaID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    AreaName VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
    Region VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL
);
```

`SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT  
    LocalBussiness.BusinessName, Address.Address, Address.Postcode, 
    Area.AreaName, Area.Region, LocalBusiness.OfficialRating, 
    LocalBusiness.min_price, LocalBusiness_max_price, 
    Phone.description, Phone.PhoneNo, 
    Email.Description, Email.email_address, 
    LocalBusiness.Web_address
FROM
    LocalBusiness 
JOIN 
    Address ON LocalBusiness.BusinessID = Address.BusinessID
JOIN 
    Area ON Address.AreaID = Area.AreaID 
         AND LocalBusiness.BusinessID = Address.BusinessID
JOIN 
    Phone ON Phone.BusinessID = LocalBusiness.BusinessID
JOIN 
    Email ON Email.BusinessID = LocalBusiness.BusinessID
WHERE 
    TypeID = '1'
ORDER BY 
    LocalBusiness.BusinessName ASC;
```

The where clause in the sql join statement written above seem to be ineffective as the some values for the TypeID return incomplete data while others return no rows at all. How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Please add example data and expected output

Comment: I'm guessing that not all not all businesses have an address, phone, and email? If that is the case, you would want to do outer joins.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Yyou repeat a condition

```
AND LocalBusiness.BusinessID=Address.BusinessID in JOIN Area
```

Try avoinding this repetition

```
SELECT LocalBussiness.BusinessName, Address.Address, Address.Postcode,  
        Area.AreaName, Area.Region, LocalBusiness.OfficialRating, 
        LocalBusiness.min_price, LocalBusiness_max_price, Phone.description,
        Phone.PhoneNo, Email.Description, Email.email_address, 
        LocalBusiness.Web_address
FROM LocalBusiness 
JOIN Address ON LocalBusiness.BusinessID=Address.BusinessID
JOIN Area ON Address.AreaID=Area.AreaID 
JOIN Phone ON Phone.BusinessID=LocalBusiness.BusinessID
JOIN Email ON Email.BusinessID=LocalBusiness.BusinessID
WHERE TypeID = '1'
ORDER BY LocalBusiness.BusinessName ASC;
```

Otherwise check th consistence of your data ..